# What would be the serious equivalent of "parody"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a suitable word.

A *parody* is a work that references some other work by making fun of it, usually having similar setting and characters but comic outcome.

What if the referencing work is not intended to be funny? For example, I'm just reading a comic clearly referencing some other comic but turning story originally intended for kids much more realistic, gitty and simply gruesome. Is there a word in English describing such a work?

Edit: After reading a few suggestions I noticed one subtlety I intended to express. Just like in the case of *parody* I'd like to indicate a sense of discussion with the original work. It's something I have an impression is missing in case of *remake* or *rework*.

Comment: Well, 'imitation' might suit you, but even though a 'parody' is frequently comic, it is not necessarily so.

Comment: Well, Merriam-Webster says about parody: "a literary or musical work in which the style of an author or work is closely imitated for comic effect or in ridicule"

Comment: Yes...ridicule and satire are often deadly serious, not at all comic.

Comment: Interestingly, Oxford says about satire: "The use of humour, irony, exaggeration, or ridicule to expose and criticize people's stupidity or vices, particularly in the context of contemporary politics and other topical issues."

Comment: As @JEL says, parody is not necessarily for comic effect, although it is most frequently used in that sense. But in renaissance music, for example, a 'parody mass' setting is the sung Catholic mass where the composer uses and varies an existing theme or melody (either their own composition or someone else's) to compose the music for the various movements of the mass (the Kyrie, the Gloria, the Sanctus and so on) - which is about as far removed from comedy or ridicule as it is possible to get.

Comment: I can't think of a single-word answer, but in this instance, does '*darker retelling* of xxx comic' work? Otherwise it might be 'inspired by xxx', 'derivative of xxx', or as you have already suggested it could be 'a story which references xxx'.

Comment: *Serious reworking of* ... ?

Comment: @Spagirl Indeed, I was originally searching for a single word, but I don't insist. In fact, I quite like the term _darker retelling_.

Comment: @JEL _The Game of Thrones_, although not referencing any particular work, is largely based on the idea of overturning common fantasy tropes. Would you say it's a parody of fantasy?

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest? Were any of those less about humor? Do you think 'satire' would work?

Comment: How about "homage?"

Comment: How about *adapation*?

Comment: Kalmar, you *could* say that, or that elements of *GoT* (not necessarily comic) parody fantasy tropes. My own take is that *GoT*, insofar as it is overall a parody of fantasy, was eaten by its mother.

Comment: Some forms are notoriously difficult to parody, because they tend to assimilate parodies (the parodies are "eaten by their mothers", if you'll forgive me quoting myself). Fantasy is one such. For example, from your description, I'd guess you were talking about a 'grotesquerie' or simply a 'grotesque', but "The grotesque is a branch of the fantastic." (*Pall Mall Gazette*, 1888)

Answer (score 2):

A reinterpretation?
Reinterpret:

> to understand and explain or show (something) in a new or different way

Rework?

> to make changes to (something, such as a piece of writing or music) in order to improve it.

Reboot?

> restart or revive (a process or sequence, especially a series of films or television programmes); give fresh impetus to.

Pastiche?

> 1. an artistic work in a style that imitates that of another work, artist, or period.
> 2. > an artistic work consisting of a medley of pieces imitating various sources.
> 3. imitate the style of (an artist or work).

Nod?

> a gesture of acknowledgement or concession to.
>
> "the device is a nod to the conventions of slapstick"

Throwback?

> a person or thing having the characteristics of a former time.
>
> "a lot of his work is a throwback to the fifties"

All definitions sourced from the *Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English*, provided by Google, or Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Your definitions of pastiche make clear that it is about style rather than content. The OP is specifically about a case where the style is what has changed ie that element of the story are retold in a different style.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I've also seen _pastiche_ defined as _a piece of writing, music, etc., that is made up of selections from different works_. I don't know if that refers to a compilation or a work which imitates the content of multiple other sources, although of course only one source is imitated in the asker's example. Anyway, I've added some more options. Now that I think about it, _reinterpretation_ is used often in this context. @Spagirl

Answer (score 2):

Consider *recast*.

> **Recast** *verb*
>   1.1 Present or organize in a different form or style.
>   *‘his doctoral thesis has been recast for the general reader’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recast)

You can say that the original story was "recast for a more sombre audience".

Answer (score 2):

I think **grim parody** is about as close as you will get.

From Hilltop Views online:

### [Banksy’s newest British exhibition a grim parody of Disneyland’s image](https://www.hilltopviewsonline.com/5672/life-and-arts/banksys-newest-british-exhibition-a-grim-parody-of-disneylands-image/)

> ...
>   It’s a theme park on the southwest coast of England, and the theme is
>   doom and gloom — **a grim parody of Disneyland**, with dreary-looking
>   rides, depressed employees garbed in Disney character costumes and
>   carnival games that only cynics enjoy.
>
> Banksy, along with over 50 other artists worked on Dismaland
>   Bemusement Park for months; it was finally opened to the public on
>   Aug. 22 and will remain so until Sept. 27, according to CNN arts
>   reporter Allyssia Alleyne.
>
> The cost? Five bucks.
>
> The draw? “A chaotic new world where you can escape from mindless
>   escapism,” reads Dismaland’s brochure.
>
> The park and the art pieces inside stink of realism.
>
> In contrast to Disney’s “It’s a wonderful life; You can do anything”
>   message, Banksy’s artwork says bleakly, “Stop dreaming.”

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **Remake** might suit your purposes. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remake),

> A *remake* is a film or television series that is based on an earlier work and tells the same story.

This doesn't mean that the story or the characters are exactly the same. For example, *10 Things I Hate About You* is a 'remake' of the Shakespeare play *The Taming Of The Shrew*; while the movie is in the genre of 'romantic comedy' it does not ridicule or parody (in the modern sense) the original work.

Even though you are talking about a graphic novel and not a film or TV series, I think you could legitimately say that one is a remake of the other.

Comment: Still, I have an impression _remake_  indicates a fairly close following of the original story. The definition you quote says it _tells the same story_ anyway and I would expect a different setting, some minor threads altered, removed or added, but the main plot remaining the same. Would it still be remake of _Romeo and Juliet_ if nobody died?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this question is super old now, but:

**reimagining** (gerund of [reimagine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reimagine))

> Reinterpret (an event, work of art, etc.) imaginatively.

Examples:

> *Cruel Intentions* is a present-day reimagining of *Dangerous Liaisons*.
>
> *Dracula 3000* is a reimagining of Bram Stoker's literary classic *Dracula*, set in the 31st century.

Answer (score 1):

'intertextuality' in critical theory is a useful term sometimes as an act of imitation, but more accurate is the use of 'appropriation', much used in postcolonial criticism. You will come across, for instance, "the writer appropriates the Arabian Nights style as an existentially redemptive form of storytelling" etc.